# Unable to attribute button to XSLT Transformation (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, transform

I am attempting to create an interface that allows me to select 3 XSLT files and merge them together to then be transformed using an XML. I have a working transformation code I am creating a user interface for.

Transformation code:

```
public static void Transform(string sXmlPath, string sXslPathBody, string sXslPathHead, string sXslPathFoot, string sXslPathMerged)
        {
            try
            {
                XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform";

                //load Xml
                XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(sXmlPath);

                //Load Body
                XElement xslt = XElement.Load(sXslPathBody);

                //Add Code To Body
                xslt.AddFirst(new XElement(ns + "include", new XAttribute("href", sXslPathFoot)));
                xslt.AddFirst(new XElement(ns + "include", new XAttribute("href", sXslPathHead)));

                XElement body = xslt.Descendants("body").Single();

                body.AddFirst(new XElement(ns + "call-template", new XAttribute("name", "Header")));
                body.Add(new XElement(ns + "call-template", new XAttribute("name", "Footer")));

                //Save Combined File
                //XElement.Save("c:\temp.xlst");
                xslt.Save(sXslPathMerged);

                XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();

                //load Combined File 
                myXslTrans.Load(sXslPathMerged);

                //Merge XML with Combined File
                XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter ("result.html", null);

                //transform Xml
                myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, myWriter);

                myWriter.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

The Transformation code works fine however I am trying to set each stage to a button which will allow me to select any 3 XSLT files I wish, as well as any XML I wish. Then a button to merge the 3 XSLT files together & create a HTML output.

Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String HeadFileSelected, BodyFileSelected, FootFileSelected, XmlFileSelected, MergeFiles;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Head
        private void openFileHead_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void header_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileHead.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                HeadFileSelected = openFileHead.FileName;

                string filename = HeadFileSelected;

                textBox2.Text = HeadFileSelected;
            }
        }

        //Body
        private void openFileBody_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void body_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileBody.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                BodyFileSelected = openFileBody.FileName;

                string filename = BodyFileSelected;

                textBox3.Text = BodyFileSelected;
            }
        }

        //Foot
        private void openFileFooter_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void footer_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileFooter.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FootFileSelected = openFileFooter.FileName;

                string filename = FootFileSelected;

                textBox4.Text = FootFileSelected;
            }
        }

        //Xml
        private void openFileXml_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void xml_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileXml.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                XmlFileSelected = openFileXml.FileName;
            }
        }

        //Merge
        private void openFileMerge_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void merge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //XmlTransformUtil objXMLTrans = new XmlTransformUtil();
            XmlTransformUtil.Transform(XmlFileSelected, BodyFileSelected, HeadFileSelected, FootFileSelected, MergeFiles);
        }
    }
```

I have managed to get the XML selection & the 3 XSLT selections to work fine it's just the Merge button that is not working as I cannot attribute the `String MergeFiles;` to `Transform(string sXslPathMerged)`

I understand why it does not work but I don't now the solution that will give me the result I need.

Comment: Why don't you use `<xsl:import>`s?

Comment: Please tag this with the language being used (C#?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out, I needed to define MergeFiles as the saved XSLT which wasn't going anywhere because it was null. Did it by adding the following in my form.

```
MergeFiles = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\TEMP.xslt";
```